# How to toggle on/off particular mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Say, I want to bind a key to turn some mode on/off. I guess, the function I need should look something like

```
(defun toggle-some-mode ()
  (if (some-mode-is-active)
    (some-mode 0)
  (some-mode 1)))

(global-set-key (kbd "some key") 'toggle-some-mode)
```

The question is what does this some-mode-is-active look like? How could I know mode is active/inactive? I don't believe there's no standard function for such a useful case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use `some-mode` to toggle, i.e., `(global-set-key (kbd "some key") 'some-mode)`. The argument of `some-mode` should be optional and if it is not present it should toggle itself.

Comment: About your question how to detect whether mode is active: If `some-mode` is defined by `define-minor-mode` it exists as function and as variable. The variable is `t` if the mode is active and `nil`otherwise.

Comment: @Tobias Thank you! Works like a charm! Don't know why I haven't thought about this option :)

Comment: Okay I wrote it as an answer. So, that this question is marked as answered in the overview of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `some-mode` to toggle, i.e., `(global-set-key (kbd "some key") 'some-mode)`. The argument of some-mode should be optional and if the argument is not present in the function call the function toggles the mode by default.

About your question how to detect whether mode is active: If `some-mode` is defined by `define-minor-mode` it exists as function and as variable. The variable `some-mode` evaluates to `t` if the mode is active and `nil` otherwise.

Comment: And something that is a bit confusing at first - if you call (some-mode) from elisp (as from a function or by evaluating the text in a buffer), if will always turn the mode on, whereas if you call it interactively (as from a keyboard binding, or using M-x), it will toggle it.